# In Cytoscape.js how can I trigger a node to redraw after its data changes?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

Does anyone know how to trigger a node to redraw?  I've got a case where the underlying data object updates its 'label' property and the only ways I can trigger cytoscape to redraw the labels are;

1. Call some combination of `.selectify()` then `.unselectify()` on the node.
2. Replace the label using `.data('label', ...)` - I actually replace it with itself.

Both of these feel a bit hacky and I presume I'm missing something obvious in the API.  Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

You don't update anything in the data you provide to Cytoscape without using the Cytoscape APIs.

If you do `node.data().foo.bar = 'baz'`, Cytoscape has no idea you've changed anything.

If you do `node.data('foo.bar', 'baz')`, Cytoscape knows you've altered the model.

Like most apps, your app probably has some model in a higher layer than Cytoscape.  So just update Cytoscape with a JSON representation of the model when your true model changes.  Assuming your model uses event emitters, just do something like `modelObj.on('change', function(){ this.node.data( this.json() ) })`.